# Track the length of video the user has played and play from the time at which the user left the last time usin GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I am using Google Could Platform for storing the video/audio files. The requirement is that the length of the videos/audios at which the user left the last time one has played it, and if one has watched the video/audio, should be tracked and the file should be played next time starting from the time one left. It's the same as Youtube does. I need help about how can we achieve it because I cannot find resources about it on Google or I am not able search it efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there is nothing really difficult. At least only one because I'm not a front end developer.

In the principle, you already know the user (already authenticated), and you know the video that they are watching.

The tricky part is to get, from the video player, in the browser, the current video time. Pick this value regularly (let say, every 10s), and post this value to an endpoint (Cloud Functions for example).

The endpoint save in database the latest event, with the userID and the videoID. Next time that the user opens the same video, set the video player to the latest saved time and that's all.

You have to decide if you want to keep the max duration of the video (in case of the user go back to review a part) or the latest. You also need to set the periodic post delay. I said 10s, that means the user can start to watch again the video up to 10s in the past. You can also add an event on OnClose to send the latest video player value,...

Comment: Yes, that totally makes sense. But the front end for us is native mobile application. So I would have to confirm it on the mobile side.

Comment: I can't answer you. I never developed a mobile app. I absolutely don't know!

Comment: Just got an update from our iOS developer. It can be done like you said on iOS side as well. Marking as answer. Thanks